# Keeping SDE for data maintenance, but use postgis for display

Tags: arcgis-server, postgis, enterprise-geodatabase

We build and maintain GIS data in a production environment with SDE on SQL 2008.  We also have a need to open up WMS and WFS that will make a complete ESRI solution really expensive.  With an ArcGIS Server Enterprise Advanced license, is it possible to replicate the data into a non-SDE postgis database and push deltas from the production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GeoServer to provide WMS/WFS direct from the SDE store. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTDOC/ArcSDE+DataStore

Comment: I haven't been able to find the *_sde.jar files for 10.0  Sorry, I didn't include that tidbit in the OP.

Comment: I'm not an ESRI user but this might help http://old.nabble.com/Where-I-can-get-jar-files-of-ArcSDE-9.3---td22224363.html

Comment: Thanks, I had to order a developer kit data over support

Answer (score 1):

You could use OGR2OGR to move data to Postgre/PostGIS and create WMS/WFS with f.i. UMN Mapserver or Geoserver.

Comment: Thanks... but that's a complete dump of a large dataset when edits have been made in the (frequently edited) production environment.

Comment: I think that will work... or at least get me closer.